# How to get child data of an entity without loading the entity in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have entities User and Report

```
class User {
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    protected Set<BattleReport> reports;
}

class Report {
    byte data;
}
```

I know user id and I need to update report data for a User without loading user. How to do it?

I've tried this way, but it doesn't work:

```
Query reportsQuery = session.createQuery("SELECT reports FROM User WHERE id = :id");
    reportsQuery.setParameter("id", id);
    List<?> list = reportsQuery.list();

    for (Object o : list) {
        Report report = (Report) o;
        report.setData(42);
        session.update(report);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Match on the id of the user of the report:

```
Query reportsQuery = session.createQuery(
    "FROM Report r WHERE r.user.id = :id");
```

Comment: report has no field user, Report table has such field, but not class

Comment: Then add the foreign key to the class. It's a very reasonae thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is:

```
SELECT u.reports FROM User u WHERE u.id = :id
```

Comment: i think deep inside of hibernate it makes left join and gets only user id from user table and reports of the user from the reports table filtering by user_id. by not loading the user i meant to not make query to get user then to get his report and then to update the report because it would be one more query.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a Criteria query on the Report table with the user_id as a constraint?
I don't know youyr database relationship or fields and, as such, can't give you a real example, but something as follow can be userfull perhaps:

[Criteria Example](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-criteria-examples/)